# Convert an array to custom string format in Spark with Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions

I created a `DataFrame` as follows:

```
import spark.implicits._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val df = Seq(
  (1, List(1,2,3)),
  (1, List(5,7,9)),
  (2, List(4,5,6)),
  (2, List(7,8,9)),
  (2, List(10,11,12)) 
).toDF("id", "list")

val df1 = df.groupBy("id").agg(collect_set($"list").as("col1"))
df1.show(false)
```

Then I tried to convert the `WrappedArray` row value to string as follows:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
def arrayToString = udf((arr: collection.mutable.WrappedArray[collection.mutable.WrappedArray[String]]) => arr.flatten.mkString(", "))

val d = df1.withColumn("col1", arrayToString($"col1"))
d: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [id: int, col1: string]

scala> d.show(false)
+---+----------------------------+
|id |col1                        |
+---+----------------------------+
|1  |1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 9            |
|2  |4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12|
+---+----------------------------+
```

What I really want is to generate an output like the following:

```
+---+----------------------------+
|id |col1                        |
+---+----------------------------+
|1  |1$2$3, 5$7$ 9               |
|2  |4$5$6, 7$8$9, 10$11$12      |
+---+----------------------------+
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need a `udf` function, a simple `concat_ws` should do the trick for you as

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val df1 = df.withColumn("list", concat_ws("$", col("list")))
            .groupBy("id")
            .agg(concat_ws(", ", collect_set($"list")).as("col1"))

df1.show(false)
```

which should give you

```
+---+----------------------+
|id |col1                  |
+---+----------------------+
|1  |1$2$3, 5$7$9          |
|2  |7$8$9, 4$5$6, 10$11$12|
+---+----------------------+
```

As usual, `udf` function should be avoided **if inbuilt functions are available** since *`udf` function would require serialization and deserialization of column data to primitive types for calculation and from primitives to columns respectively*

even more concise you can avoid the `withColumn` step as

```
val df1 = df.groupBy("id")
            .agg(concat_ws(", ", collect_set(concat_ws("$", col("list")))).as("col1"))
```

I hope the answer is helpful

Comment: This is a better approach, I should have considered everything and not only the udf :)